# Adding Values to Each Other

Tags: javascript

How would one go about stacking values to each other? So if you were to click on a button, it would add the numbers to each other and keep stacking on. I'm trying to add the values to a P tag's innerHTML that calculates the total but I just figured out how to display its true value without the addition of additional values.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const p = document.querySelector('p')

function addCal() {
  const inputVal = input.value

  p.innerHTML = inputVal
}

button.addEventListener('click', addCal)
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<button>Add Calories</button>
<p>0</p>
```

Comment: Get existing number from the `<p>` text ... convert to number...convert input value to number and add together for sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the last value somewhere and add that to the newest number.

Keep in mind that all values gotten from HTML are strings, so they must be converted (implicitly or explicitly) to numbers before math can be done. Also, `.innerHTML` is for when you are getting/ setting strings that contain HTML. When you aren't doing that, use `.textContent`.

Also note that you should always verify user input is what you think it is before you operate on it. What if the user doesn't enter anything, but clicks the button anyway? What if they enter non-numeric data?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

var total = null;  // The running total will be kept here

function addCal() {
  const inputVal = input.value;
  
  // .parseInt() and .parseFloat() are two ways of
  // explicitly converting strings that contain number
  // characters to numbers. With .parseInt() the secon
  // argument is the radix, which specifies what numeral
  // system to use (base 10 here).
  total = total + parseInt(inputVal, 10);
  p.textContent = total;
}

button.addEventListener('click', addCal)
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<button>Add Calories</button>
<p>0</p>
```

Comment: Small edit: you need to check if the `inputVal` is not empty, otherwise you will get **NaN** as your result.

Comment: @Azuloo There's a lot of additional checks to be done (value should be trimmed before worked on, etc.), but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum all the input values.

1) Pick up all the inputs with `querySelectorAll`.

2) Then iterate over the input elements with `reduce` adding each input's value to the total sum. We use `+input.value` to coerce the string type of the value to a number.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

function addCal() {
  para.textContent = [...inputs].reduce((sum, input) => {
    return sum += +input.value;
  }, 0);
}

button.addEventListener('click', addCal, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<button>Add Calories</button>
<p>0</p>
```

Comment: Kind of an overly complex answer given the simplicity of the question.

Comment: Except I learned how reduce worked with question just like this way back when I was starting out. There were a lot of answers like yours, and some that showed more complex but more illuminating ways to solve the problem. If you're only shown simple explanations the less opportunity there is to grow as a programmer imo.

Comment: If the OP doesn't know how to store a simple value, showing arrays and spread operators and arrow functions isn't really providing a learning process. You didn't even explain those concepts in your answer so how would someone learn from it?

Comment: And, you've changed the UI to something that is not what the OP is asking about, which makes your answer irrelevant. You are answering a question that was not asked.

Answer (score 0):

Just do convert p tag value to int and then added up. like

```
function addCal() {
   const inputVal = input.value  
   p.innerHTML = ( parseInt(p.innerHTML) + parseInt(inputVal) )  
}
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` should not be used here

Comment: Why make a 3rd party site example, when you can just include a code snippet right here? And, yes, it works, but `.innerHTML` should not be used here. Just because something works, doesn't mean it's correct.